# image url showing cors error in angular but working fine javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, cors

we have used aws s3 for image storing. When we tried convert image to base64. code working fine javascript but code is not angular

**javascript code:**

```
function getBase64Image(imgUrl, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    // onload fires when the image is fully loadded, and has width and height
    img.onload = function(){
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
          dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

      callback(dataURL); // the base64 string

    };

    // set attributes and src 
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); //
    img.src = imgUrl;

}
this.getBase64Image("imageURL", function(base64image){
     console.log(base64image);
});
```

It is working fine in javascript but angular throws below error

**Access to image at 'https://examplecros.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/images5.jpg' from origin 'http//localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
5.jpg:1

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED**

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 and your local are 2 different domains and you have already consider to set its corresponding property:

> img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'.

Also, you have to config cross domain setting in your backend by this syntax:

> CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True.

If the problem exist yet, try adding a random parameter to your image URL to avoid your app getting the img from local cache:

> img.src = imgUrl + '?r=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);

I used the above steps and solved my problem witch was similar to yours.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352403/cors-error-for-adding-image-from-another-domain-in-jspdf-in-angular-8)

Answer (score 0):

This is a security restriction from the browser because the origins are different.
You can do the following workarounds to do this.

add,

```
img.crossOrigin = '*'
```

and
try using pre-signed URL for the object in s3(as image src) instead of direct url